# Text below is moves when I put a text shadow above

Tags: html, css

so I have text on the top when you hover over it, it gains a box shadow. but unfortunately, the text below it gets moved.

I have searched for a while but could not find any solutions. Please help.
edit:

```css
butto{
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  background-color:white;
  padding:2px;
  cursor: default;
 
}
butto:hover{
  background-color:#e3e3e3;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px grey;
  
}
html{
background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<butto onClick="print()" class='no-print'>Print</butto>
<p style="color:white;">Text below!</p>
```

Comment: please provide code snippet for better assessment

Comment: I have did the edit with the code snippet

Comment: What is `<butto>` ???

Comment: @ShebaDoge nice, answered.

Comment: <butto> was used because when you press space after clicking a button it will activate again. I did a non-syntax tag and I styled it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `display: inline-block` to `content`
also read what is `display: content` [here](https://caniuse.com/?search=display%3A%20content)

```css
butto{
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  background-color:white;
  padding:2px;
  cursor: default;
 
}
butto:hover{
  background-color:#e3e3e3;
  display: content;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px grey;
  
}
html{
background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<butto onClick="print()" class='no-print'>Print</butto>
<p style="color:white;">Text below!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move `display` property from the hovered to the general state:

```css
butto {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 2px;
  cursor: default;
  display: inline-block;
}

butto:hover {
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px grey;
}

html {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<butto onClick="print()" class='no-print'>Print</butto>
<p style="color:white;">Text below!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your text below is being pushed, is because you have `display: inline-block` property assigned to the hover class.
Removing it will bring it to default `display: initial` and will solve your problem.

P.S. also make sure to update `<butto>` tag to `<button>`, as that might result an unexpected behaviour while developing.

Comment: Thanks but btw I don't want <button> because after clicking it if you press space/enter it will activate again so I just made it like that.

Comment: @ShebaDoge then I suggest you use <div>.